# Python calculate the number of year in date column

Tags: python

I've recently start coding with Python, and I'm struggling to calculate the number of years between the current date and a given date.

[Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgvHy.png)

I would like to calculate the number of year for each column.
I tried this but it's not working:

```
def Number_of_years(d1,d2):
    if d1 is not None:
        return relativedelta(d2,d1).years

for col in df.select_dtypes(include=['datetime64[ns]']):
    df[col]=Number_of_years(df[col],date.today())
```

Can anyone help me find a solution to this?

Comment: "it's not working" is not a description of your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that the format of dates is day/month/year.

Given this format is same for all the grids, you can parse the date using the `datetime` module like so:

```
from datetime import datetime # import module

def numberOfYears(element):
    # parse the date string according to the fixed format
    date = datetime.strptime(element, '%d/%m/%Y')

    # return the difference in the years
    return datetime.today().year - date.year

# make things more interesting by vectorizing this function
function = np.vectorize(numberOfYears)

# This returns a numpy array containing difference between years.
# call this for each column, and you should be good
difference = function(df.Date_creation)
```

Answer (score 0):

You code is basically right, but you're operating over a pandas series so you can't just call `relativedelta` directly:

```
def number_of_years(d1,d2):
        return relativedelta(d2,d1).years

for col in df.select_dtypes(include=['datetime64[ns]']):
    df[col]= df[col].apply(lambda d: number_of_years(x, date.today()))
```